# Angular only show field is required when input field is touched or clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

When the getStarted function is called it will determine the condition if is existing is false I wanna set lastName and firstName from formgroup as required , it is working but if you look at the image example below when setRequired is executed the is required error is showing without me clicking the input field. The Last name is required for example should only show if setRequired is called and user touch or click the for example lastname field. Any idea guys ? I really need help on this one. Appreciated. Thank you.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsx1P.png)

```
    getStarted(isExisting: boolean) { 
     if(isExisting === false) {
}
    this.setRequired ()
    }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initFormGroup();
}
```

#ts code

```
initFormGroup() {
  this.modelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [this.model.id || 0],
    emailAddress: [this.model.emailAddress, Validators.required],
    firstName: this.model.firstName,
    roleId: this.model.roleId,
    lastName: this.model.lastName,
  });

}
```

```
setRequired {
    this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required)
 

}
  if () {
    this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required)
  }
```

#html

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="isExisting === false" class="custom" style="width: 684px;">
                <mat-card-content style="height:30px;">
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
                                    First name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="lastName">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('lastName').hasError('required') && isExisting === false">
                                Last name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="phoneNumber">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <mat-label>Company Name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="companyName">
                                <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                                <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('companyName').hasError('required') && isExisting === false">
                                    Company Name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                                
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="title">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: @AJT82, I was not able to explain well the question from the previous one , please don't delete this

Comment: Your question won't be deleted. And you can always edit your previous question :)

Comment: @AJT82 do you have some idea sir with my question ? I tried solving it ..

Comment: Yeah, since you have this scenario to disabling (and enabling?) I think you need an error state matcher to only show messages when field has been touched: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown I've never encountered this scenario myself, but at least that I what I suggest you start with.

Comment: @AJT82, could you please provide example bsaed on my code Sir ?

Comment: Hmm... just got a thought. Please post the full html for the form. Or is the requirement of required only decided when page loads? Can user make the choice in the form, a button or something?

Comment: done updating @AJT82

Comment: Where is the form tags, I asked to post whole form, also you didn't answer any of my questions in previpus comment.